# I created a texture in Photoshop for my object and for whatever reason the UV overlay is on the texture

Tags: texturing, uv

[image: My object]

Here is the texture on the object in blender. Keep in mind I am super new to Blender, I cant find anything explaining what's causing this issue. As you can see the UV map is on my object even though it's not on the texture.

Comment: Post an image of the texture. post an image of the material. "For whatever reason" is not a real reason.

Comment: Hi. Please specify what you are asking for. Thanks.

Comment: hello, could you please share your file (with the image texture packed inside): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/